# How can I write a text file to Desktop in c++ Visual Studios?

Tags: c++, text

I'm wanting to create a Text file on the Desktop of any user's computer who I send this program to. Essentially I am wanting to figure out how to find their **desktop path** as well as create a **.txt** file to fill with info to throw on their desktop as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create file on desktop in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359627/create-file-on-desktop-in-c)

Comment: No, I want code to actually find the desktop path of whoever i send this code to.

Answer (score 2):

Start by getting the path to the desktop:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    wchar_t* pszDesktopFolderPath = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, KF_FLAG_DONT_VERIFY, NULL, &pszDesktopFolderPath);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        std::wstring strFileName(pszDesktopFolderPath);
        strFileName = strFileName + L"\\" + L"MyFileName.txt";
        CoTaskMemFree(pszDesktopFolderPath);
        pszDesktopFolderPath = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then [_wfopen_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx) or any other I/O open API (CreateFile, open, etc..) to

Comment: Oh wait - it's a variable name thing.  Fixed.  But you could have figured that out yourself...

Comment: wchar_t szDesktopFolderPath[260] ERROR: argument of type "wchar_t*" is incompatible with parameter of type "PWSTR *"

Comment: Also. szFolderPath is undefined.  I have no clue like what wstring is so Idk why it thinks its undefined.

Comment: fixed the szDesktop error, you forgot the *... But I still am getting that szfolderPath is undefined. do I just declare this as a string?

Comment: Yea I have no idea what the hell this line is doing std::wstring strFileName(szFolderPath);.... It says szFolderPath is undefined. I tried string szFolderPath = "". stil didnt work

Comment: Testing would have been quicker you know.

Comment: @AlexM. - Testing was getting in the way of eating halloween candy.