# How to create a file in a specific directory in c++11 ?!

Tags: c++, c++11

this is the code 
how can i create Title.txt in a specific directory such as desktop ! ?

```
ifstream file ;
file.open("Title.txt");
file.close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create file on desktop in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359627/create-file-on-desktop-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the complete path to the file in the open() function:

```
file.open("C:\\Users\\Foo\\Desktop\\bar.txt");
```

If you need the folder to be user-specific, you can use the $HOME and $USER linux environment variables and their windows equivalents.

EDIT: as somebody pointed out (thanks), you need to escape the backslashes on Windows, as they are used as escape characters in C. On Linux, you don't need to do that, as the path uses forward slashes.

Comment: Wrong. ``\`` is C string special escape character (as shown in the possible duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
             ofstream file;
             char name[81];
             file.open("C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\tittle.txt"); //path

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for example 
File.open("C:\Users\sample\Desktop\title.txt");

Answer (score 0):

you simply write the directory you want when opening the file and if it doesn't find it there it should make anew one